# How to return random records in Neo4j using Cypher?

Tags: random, neo4j, cypher

I have query like this:

```
$query = "MATCH (U:User)
          RETURN U
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT 100";
```

But when I run this, this shows errors. It says:

> Caught Exception: Unable to execute query [400]: Headers: Array (
>   [Content-Type] => application/json; charset=UTF-8; stream=true
>   [Access-Control-Allow-Origin] => * [Transfer-Encoding] => chunked
>   [Server] => Jetty(9.0.z-SNAPSHOT) ) Body: Array ( [message] => ORDER
>   BY expressions must be deterministic. For instance, you cannot use the
>   rand() function in the expression [exception] => PatternException
>   [fullname] => org.neo4j.cypher.PatternException [stacktrace] => Array
>   ( [0] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.commands.SortItem.apply(SortItem.scala:30)
>   [1] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.ExecutionContextComparer$class.compareBy(SortPipe.scala:43)
>   [2] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe.compareBy(TopPipe.scala:33)
>   [3] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TopPipe.scala:38)
>   [4] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TopPipe.scala:38)
>   [5] => scala.Option.forall(Option.scala:226) [6] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe$$anonfun$1.apply(TopPipe.scala:38)
>   [7] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe$$anonfun$1.apply(TopPipe.scala:38)
>   [8] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(TopPipe.scala:56)
>   [9] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe$$anonfun$internalCreateResults$1.apply(TopPipe.scala:49)
>   [10] => scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
>   [11] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.HeadAndTail.foreach(SlicePipe.scala:72)
>   [12] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.TopPipe.internalCreateResults(TopPipe.scala:49)
>   [13] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:71)
>   [14] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.pipes.PipeWithSource.createResults(Pipe.scala:68)
>   [15] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder.org$neo4j$cypher$internal$compiler$v2_0$executionplan$ExecutionPlanBuilder$$prepareStateAndResult(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:149)
>   [16] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:126)
>   [17] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anonfun$2.apply(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:125)
>   [18] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.compiler.v2_0.executionplan.ExecutionPlanBuilder$$anon$6.execute(ExecutionPlanBuilder.scala:50)
>   [19] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.internal.ExecutionPlanWrapperForV2_0.execute(CypherCompiler.scala:93)
>   [20] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:61)
>   [21] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.scala:65)
>   [22] =>
>   org.neo4j.cypher.javacompat.ExecutionEngine.execute(ExecutionEngine.java:78)
>   [23] =>
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.web.CypherService.cypher(CypherService.java:100)
>   [24] => java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) [25] =>
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.transactional.TransactionalRequestDispatcher.dispatch(TransactionalRequestDispatcher.java:139)
>   [26] =>
>   org.neo4j.server.rest.security.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:112)
>   [27] => java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ) )

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You'll need to order by a node property, not a function. You could do the following (if your node contains e.g. the property 'name'):

```
MATCH (u:User)
WITH u, rand() AS number
RETURN u
ORDER BY number
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Can be quite slow in large dataset.

Comment: Your edit has made the code not match the prose, making the whole answer a bit nonsensical. -1.